# How to randomly set the elements in Javascript Array to zero?

Tags: javascript, matrix

I have a javascript matrix class with constructor

```
    class Matrix {
  constructor(rows, cols) {
    this.rows = rows;
    this.cols = cols;
    this.data = Array(this.rows).fill().map(() => Array(this.cols).fill(0));
  }
```

Now I have a matrix namely `weights_1` which the size is 32 * 64

How to randomly selects some elements in `weights_1` and make them to zero? for example, I want to make 30% of elements in the `weights_1` to zero.

Comment: `Array.from({length: 100}, _ => Math.random() < 0.3 ? 0 : 666);`

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
this.data = Array(this.rows).fill().map(() => Array(this.cols).fill(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) > 30 ? 1 : 0));
```

This would randomly set (roughly) 30% of the values to 0 and the others to 1.

Comment: Hi, is there any way just change weights_1? because I have already generated a matrix named weights_1, and it already has values in this matrix, and I would like to change some of them to zero, and other elements will keep the same.

Comment: You'd have to do `weights_1.map((arr) => arr.map((val) => Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) > 30 ? val : 0))`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that'll make sure the result is 30% instead of just "probably around 30%." The variable naming should make everything self-explanatory. I used [randojs](https://randojs.com) for the shuffling, but you can refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array) about shuffling in javascript if you prefer to do that part yourself.

```js
class Matrix {
  constructor(rows, cols) {
    this.rows = rows;
    this.cols = cols;
    this.data = Array(this.rows).fill().map(() => Array(this.cols).fill(999));
  }

  zeroOutPercentage(percentage) {
    var totalWeigths = this.rows * this.cols;
    var numberOfWeightsToZeroOut = Math.floor(totalWeigths * (percentage / 100));
    var weightsToZeroOut = randoSequence(totalWeigths).slice(0, numberOfWeightsToZeroOut);

    for (var i = 0; i < weightsToZeroOut.length; i++) {
      var row = Math.floor(weightsToZeroOut[i] / this.rows);
      var col = weightsToZeroOut[i] % this.rows;
      this.data[row][col] = 0;
    }
  }
}

var weights_1 = new Matrix(20, 20);
weights_1.zeroOutPercentage(30);
console.log(weights_1.data);
```

```html
<script src="https://randojs.com/2.0.0.js"></script>
```